# Maven system scope dependency does not copy source jar to build target jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am in the situation right now, where I can not put a compiled jar into our custom maven repository. Our repository is configured in my maven config. What I am trying to achieve is to use the local compiled jar file of the dependency as a replacement for the checked out file from our file server.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>*filepath*</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This will find the file and compile my jar, but it will not copy the dependency into the lib directory inside the compiled jar, meaning my application can not run. Is there any way to link a local jar file and make it actually appear in the resulting jar files "lib" directory?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`copy-rename-maven-plugin`](https://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/).

```
<build>
   <!-- ... -->

   <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>copy-my-jar</id>
           <phase>process-classes</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>copy</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
            <sourceFile>*filepath*</sourceFile>
            <destinationFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib/my.jar</destinationFile>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
      <executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I have worked around it now, by copying the file into my local repository cache manually.